# How to calculate the frequency of a list of symbols in Python

Tags: python, frequency

I am trying to calculate the frequency of the amount of times each symbol is shown in a list. So far I have this code which doesn't seem to work correctly because it shows this error message below...

```
uniques = set(words.split())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

This is my code so far...

```
def calculate_frequency():
        words = ()
        uniques = set(words.split())
        freqs = [(item, words.split.count(item)) for item in uniques]
        print(freqs)
```

The symbols which I want to know the frequency of and stored in the variable 'words' are shown below...

Comment: *doesn't seem to work correctly* is *never* a proper problem description. Please do be specific in your descriptions.

Comment: And by symbols, do you mean the whole character sequence or individual characters? E.g. are you counting `#`, `+`, etc. or `#+/084&"` as a symbol? If the latter, why are you using `set()` at all? That'd only guarantee that all 'symbols' have a count of 1.

Comment: What's 'words=()'? Are all the words contained in a tuple?

Comment: Martijn, I want to know the frequency of each character. e.g. # appears 2 times, % appears 6 times....

Comment: first assign ur symbols to variable words then perform split

Comment: @user3662176: so why do you use `words = ()` if you already have a `words` global?

Comment: Please, don't change your question to match code shown in answers; I addressed your *original* code, both in comments and in the answer, and your error message also reflects the original problem. Lets not change history here.

Answer (score 4):

For frequency counts, use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and just feed it the whole text; we can remove newlines by splitting and rejoining.

I'm assuming `words` is a global string with newlines it it; split on newlines with `str.splitlines()`:

```
from collections import Counter

def calculate_frequency():
    freqs = Counter(''.join(words.splitlines()))
    for symbol, count in freqs.most_common():
        print symbol, count
```

This produces a frequency list sorted from most common to least common symbol.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> words = '''\
... #+/084&"
... #3*#%#+
... 8%203:
... ,1$&
... !-*%
... .#7&33&
... #*#71%
... &-&641'2
... #))85
... 9&330*
... '''
>>> def calculate_frequency():
...     freqs = Counter(''.join(words.splitlines()))
...     for symbol, count in freqs.most_common():
...         print symbol, count
... 
>>> calculate_frequency()
# 8
& 7
3 6
% 4
* 4
1 3
0 3
8 3
) 2
+ 2
- 2
2 2
4 2
7 2
! 1
" 1
$ 1
' 1
, 1
/ 1
. 1
5 1
6 1
9 1
: 1
```

Comment: @user3662176: I don't know, does it? You haven't shown is nearly enough of the rest of your code. I've demonstrated that *given the assumptions I documented*, the code works.

Comment: @user3662176: are you using Python 3 perhaps? Then it's `print(symbol, count)`.

Comment: @user3662176: You are using indentation wrong there, and the session there has no `words` name either. Please, be more complete in your questions; try to include error information. If you are *this new* to programming, Stack Overflow is not your tutorial. Try to follow a real tutorial first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Counter()` to find the frequency of each character.

```
from collections import Counter

a="@#@#$%$#^@&"
print Counter(a)
#output Counter({'@': 3, '#': 3, '$': 2, '%': 1, '&': 1, '^': 1})
```

If you have a list of strings such as `a = ["#@#$$","@#$@$$","@#!@#!@"]` then you can use `Counter(''.join(a))`.

Comment: When I try this code an error appears on COUNTER(a)

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ I have made an edit to your answer, modifying some spelling/grammar and also fixing a mistake in your code where you had a string with `'#@#$$"` as opposed to `"#@#$$"` which caused a SyntaxError.

Comment: @user3662176 are you using the function as `COUNTER(a)`? If so that is incorrect, Python is a case-sensitive language and the correct use is `Counter(a)`.

Comment: Nope I am using it as Counter(a)

Comment: uniques = set(words.split())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @user3662176 see . u should intialize words with values .ur using empty words there it does not have split(). please understand .words should contain values